# Google Compute Engine: how to set hostname permanently?

Tags: google-compute-engine

How do I set the hostname of an instance in GCE permanently? I can set it via hostname,but after reboot it is gone again.

I tried to feed in metadata (hostname:f.q.d.n), but that did not do the job. But it should work via metadata (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/tree/master/google-startup-scripts).

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most simple way to achieve it is creating a simple script and that's what I have done.

I have stored the hostname in the instance metadata and then I retrieve it every time the system restarts in order to set the hostname using a cron job.

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata <instance> --metadata hostname=<new_hostname> 
$ sudo crontab -e
```

And this is the line that must be appended in crontab

```
@reboot hostname $(curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

After these steps, every time you restart your instance it will have the hostname `<new_hostname>`.
You can check it in the prompt or with the command: `hostname`

Comment: Appears to be a viable solution. But I settled with the advice not to change the hostname, because it is not necessary. All outside appearing hostnames can/should be set in the respective applications.

Comment: Nice solution @Adrián,  thanks! But doesn't work for me. It seems that google sets the hostname after the startup pf the cron daemon...

Comment: Inspired by this solution, I wrote a patch that preserves your hostname from overwriting from Google. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38344684/1325832

Comment: This did not work for me - another solution here did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607475/8177355

Answer (score 14):

You need to remove the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/google_hostname.sh`

```
rm -rf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/google_hostname.sh
rm -rf /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/google_set_hostname
```

It's worth noting that this script is needed in order to run `gcloud beta compute instances create` with the `--hostname` flag. If this script is absent on a base image, new VM instances will preserve the source hostname/FQDN!

Comment: This simply fix the problem

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Edit rc.local

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add your line under the rest:

```
hostname *your.hostname.com*
```

Make sure to run the following after for the script to be executed

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

Reboot, and profit.

Comment: This does not work - the hostname is not resolvable outside of that one machine.

Comment: Setting the hostname is intended to be local only; changing DNS is a different question.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't possible. [Please take a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313049/configuring-fqdn-for-gce-instance-on-startup) The following [article](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#default) explains that the "hostname" is part of the default metadata entries and it is not possible to manually edit any of the default metadata pairs. As such, you would need to use a script or something else to change the hostname every time the system restarts, otherwise it will automatically get re-synced with the metadata server on every reboot.

You can find information on startup scripts for GCE in [this article](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript). You can [visit this one](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#updatinginstancemetadata) for info on how to apply the script to an instance.

Comment: I don't mind to use a script to set the hostname at boot time. BUt don't know, how to fill in metadata to which script.

Comment: You can visit https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript for the article on 'startup scripts'. I will also update my answer to include this information. This way it will run every time at startup. When you're specifying which script to run, you can use local file, a file from Google Cloud Storage or a URL. You can visit https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#updatinginstancemetadata for information on how to update the metadata for your instance in order to apply a startup script.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create a simple startup-script to do the jobs:

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata <instance-name> --zone <instance-zone> --metadata startup-script='#! /bin/bash 
hostname <hostname>'
```

Notice that if you already have a startup-script you need to add to the existing startup-script below command or you will replace all the startup-script:

```
$ hostname instance-name
```

Answer (score 3):

I was lucky to set hostname at GCE running CentOS.
Source: [desantolo.com](https://desantolo.com/2016/12/how-to-setup-mailjet-on-exim-for-cpanel-dnsonly-on-google-cloud/)

1. Click EDIT on your instance
2. Go to "Custom metadata" section
3. Add  `hostname` + `your.hostname.tld` (change "your.hostname.tld" to your actual hostname
4. run `curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`
5. run `sudo env EDITOR=nano crontab -e` to edit crontab
6. add line `@reboot hostname $(curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")`
7. On your keyboard `Ctrl` + `X`
8. On your keyboard hit `Y`
9. On your keyboard hit `Enter`
10. run `reboot`
11. after system rebooted, run `hostname` and see if your changes applied

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone finds this solution does not work for them on GCS instance.  Then I suggest you try using exit hooks as described by Google Support.

> In fact, some distributions of Linux like CentOS and Debian use
>   dhclient-script script to configure the network parameters of the
>   machine. This script is invoked from time to time by dhclient which is
>   dynamic host configuration protocol client and provides a means for
>   configuring one or more network interfaces using the DHCP protocol,
>   BOOTP protocol, or if these protocols fail, by statically assigning an
>   address.
>
> The following text is a quote from the man (manual) page of 
>   dhclient-script:
>
> After  all  processing  has  completed,  /usr/sbin/dhclient-script 
>   checks  for  the  presence  of  an  executable
>          /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks  script,  which  if  present  is  invoked using the ´.´ command.  The exit status of
>          dhclient-script will be passed to dhclient-exit-hooks in the exit_status shell variable, and will always  be  zero
>          if  the  script  succeeded at the task for which it was invoked.   The rest of the environment as described previ‐
>          ously for dhclient-enter-hooks is also present.   The /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks script can modify the valid of
>          exit_status to change the exit status of dhclient-script.
>
> That being said, by taking a look into the code snippet of
>   dhclient-script, we can see the script checks for the existence of an
>   executable /etc/dhcp/dhclient-up-hooks script and all scripts in
>   /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ directory.
>
> ```
> ETCDIR="/etc/dhcp"
>
> 193 exit_with_hooks() {
> 194     exit_status="${1}"
> 195 
> 196     if [ -x ${ETCDIR}/dhclient-exit-hooks ]; then
> 197         . ${ETCDIR}/dhclient-exit-hooks
> 198     fi
> 199 
> 200     if [ -d ${ETCDIR}/dhclient-exit-hooks.d ]; then
> 201         for f in ${ETCDIR}/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/*.sh ; do
> 202             if [ -x ${f} ]; then
> 203                 . ${f}204             fi
> 205         done
> 206     fi
> 207     
> 208     exit ${exit_status}209 }
> ```
>
> Therefore, in order to modify the hostname of your Linux VM you can
>   create a custom script with .sh extension and place it in
>   /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/ directory. If this directory does not
>   exist, you can create it. The content of the custom script will be:
>
> ```
> hostname YourFQDN.sh
> ```

>

> be sure to make this new .sh file executable:
>
> ```
>  chmod +x YourFQDN.sh
> ```

Source: (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/olG_nXZ-Jaw/Y9HMl4mlBwAJ)

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I understand Adrián's answer.  It seems overly complex since you have to run a script each boot why not just use hostname?

vi /etc/rc.local

add:

hostname your_hostname

thats it. tested and working.  no need to fiddle with metadata and such.

Comment: I think Adrián's solution is good when you want to change the hostname by just changing metadata of your instance. You can clone the server, change the metadata and it will work. Otherwise you need to log into the server, edit the file, change the hostname, etc.

Comment: Perhaps this will help someone; the reason this is not viable is because GCE resets the hostname every reboot, unless one of the solutions described above is used. (script, cron)

Answer (score 1):

Non-cron/metadata/script solution.

Edit /etc/dhclient-(network-interface).conf or create one if it doesn't exist.

Example:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhclient-eth0.conf
```

Then add the following line, replacing the desired FQDN between the double quotes:

```
supersede host-name "hostname.domain-name";
```

Persists between reboots and *hostname* and *hostname -f* works as intended.

Comment: In Centos7 working but if added "something.com" then only something is showing on hostname, Period is skipping

Comment: That's the expected behavior, to display _something.com_, "-f" argument is required to hostname command, as in: `hostname -f`

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Debian.

The `dhclient` sets the hostname using DHCP

You can override this by creating a custom hook script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/custom_set_hostname` that would read the hostname from `/etc/hostname`:

```
if [ -f "/etc/hostname" ]; then
    new_host_name=$(cat /etc/hostname)
fi
```

The script must have the execute permission.

It's important to set the `new_host_name` variable and not calling the `hostname` command directly as any call to the `hostname` command will be overriden by another hook or the `dhclient-script` which uses this variable

Answer (score 1):

When creating a VM, you can specify a custom FQDN hostname as an optional parameter. This feature is currently in Beta.

```
$ gcloud beta compute instances create INSTANCE_NAME --hostname example.hostname
```

This should work across OSes, and prevent the need for workaround scripts.
More info in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm).

-- Sirui (Product Manager, Google Compute Engine)

Answer (score 0):

In my CentOS VMs I found that the script `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/google_hostname.sh`, installed by the `google-compute-engine` RPM, actually changed the hostname. This happens when the instance gets its IP address during boot.

While it's not the long-term solution I really want, for now I simply deleted this script. The hostname I set with `hostnamectl` now persists after a reboot.

The script is likely to be in exactly the same place in Debian/Ubuntu VMs, but of course I don't run any of those.

Answer (score 0):

There is some hack you can do to achieve this as i did. Just do:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

This command actually makes the file "(i)mmutable", which means even root can't change it (unless root does chattr -i /etc/hosts first, of course).

As above, you can undo this with sudo chattr -i /etc/hosts

Cheer!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to fix this is to set up a startup script with custom metadata.

```
Key :startup-script 
Value: 
#! /bin/bash 
hostname <desired hostname>
```