# How can I set a static hostname in google cloud VM?

Tags: static, google-cloud-platform, cloud, hostname

I want to configure a static hostname for my google cloud VM instance as currently its reverted to default hostname once the instance is restarted.

I have followed a few tutorials but none of those worked and thus need a permanent solution.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The hostname in Google Cloud Platform is used for [internal DNS resolution by the metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns) and is part of the default metadata for your instance. Changing it would break a few things. If you want to check what's your instance's hostname registered on the metadata server you would do this:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/hostname -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

But actually changing that metadata manually is [not possible](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#default), but there are several workarounds that might work for you. [See this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25317062/9176789)